# Anyway to make case statements on rankings smarter?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to group my ranks into chunks of data. I thought about using CASE statements, but that not only looks silly, but it's also slow

Any tips on how this can be improved?

Please note chunks vary in size (first listing the top 100, then chunks of 100, then chunks of 1000, then one chunk of 5000 and 3 other chunks of 15K)

```
select   
  transaction_code
  ,row_number() over (order by SALES_AMOUNT desc) as rank
  ,SALES_AMOUNT
  ,CASE 
    WHEN rank <=100 THEN to_varchar(rank)
    WHEN rank <=200 then '101-200'
    WHEN rank <=300 then '201-300'
    WHEN rank <=400 then '301-400'
    WHEN rank <=500 then '401-500'
    WHEN rank <=1000 then '501-1000'
    WHEN rank <=1500 then '1001-1500'
    WHEN rank <=2000 then '1501-2000'
    WHEN rank <=2500 then '2001-2500'
    WHEN rank <=3000 then '2501-3000'
    WHEN rank <=3500 then '3001-3500'
    WHEN rank <=4000 then '3501-4000'
    WHEN rank <=4500 then '4001-4500'
    WHEN rank <=5000 then '4501-5000'
    WHEN rank <=5500 then '5001-5500'
    WHEN rank <=6000 then '5501-6000'
    WHEN rank <=6500 then '6001-6500'
    WHEN rank <=7000 then '6501-7000'
    WHEN rank <=7500 then '7001-7500'
    WHEN rank <=8000 then '7501-8000'
    WHEN rank <=8500 then '8001-8500'
    WHEN rank <=9000 then '8501-9000'
    WHEN rank <=95000 then '9001-9500'
    WHEN rank <=10000 then '9501-10000'
    WHEN rank <=15000 then '10001-15000'
    WHEN rank <=30000 then '15001-30000'
    WHEN rank <=45000 then '30001-45000'
    WHEN rank <=60000 then '45001-60000'
    ELSE 'Bottom'
   END AS "TRANSACTION GROUPS"
```

Comment: Are you open to using a table variable to store your ranking categories and joining to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way is to create a lookup table that maps rank into a group name. You could do it using a stateful JavaScript UDF (initializing the map just once).

But you can also just do it in SQL

#### Table definition

Simple mapping from a number to a string

```
create or replace table rank2group(rank integer, grp string);
```

#### UDF to generate group name

Your code is indeed very long.

Instead, we can create a function that for a given rank, `group_size`, and `group_base` (number from which groups of `group_size` form), generates a string.

Note, this function will be slower than your code, as it generates a string from input, but we'll only use it to fill the lookup table, so it doesn't matter.

```
create or replace function group_name(rank integer, group_base integer, group_size integer)
returns varchar
as $$
  (group_base + 1 + group_size * floor((rank - 1 - group_base) / group_size))
  || '-' || 
  (group_base + group_size + group_size * floor((rank - 1 - group_base) / group_size))
$$;
```

Example outputs:

```
select group_name(101, 100, 100), group_name(1678, 500, 500), group_name(15000, 10000, 5000);
---------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
 GROUP_NAME(101, 100, 100) | GROUP_NAME(1678, 500, 500) | GROUP_NAME(15000, 10000, 5000) |
---------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
 101-200                   | 1501-2000                  | 10001-15000                    |
---------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

#### Table data generation

We'll generate values that map range `1 .. 60000` only, using Snowflake generators, `group_name`, and your simplified `CASE` statement:

create or replace table rank2group(rank integer, grp string);

```
insert into rank2group
select rank,
CASE 
    WHEN rank <=100 THEN to_varchar(rank)
    -- groups of size 100, starting at 100
    WHEN rank <=500 then group_name(rank, 100, 100)                                                    
    WHEN rank <=10000 then group_name(rank, 500, 500)
    -- groups of size 5000, starting at 10000
    WHEN rank <=15000 then group_name(rank, 10000, 5000) 
    WHEN rank <=60000 then group_name(rank, 15000, 15000)
    ELSE 'Bottom'
END AS "TRANSACTION GROUPS"
from (
    select row_number() over (order by 1) as rank
    from table(generator(rowCount=>60000))
);
```

#### Usage

To use it, we simply join on `rank`. 
Note, you need an `outer join` followed by `ifnull` for the `Bottom` values. 
Example, using a generated `input` that creates exponentially increasing numbers:

```
with input as (
  select 1 + (seq8() * seq8() * seq8()) AS rank
  from table(generator(rowCount=>50))
)
select input.rank, ifnull(grp, 'Bottom') grp
from input left outer join rank2group on input.rank = rank2group.rank
order by input.rank;
--------+-------------+
  RANK  |     GRP     |
--------+-------------+
 1      | 1           |
 2      | 2           |
 9      | 9           |
 28     | 28          |
 65     | 65          |
 126    | 101-200     |
 217    | 201-300     |
 344    | 301-400     |
 513    | 501-1000    |
 730    | 501-1000    |
 1001   | 1001-1500   |
 1332   | 1001-1500   |
 1729   | 1501-2000   |
 2198   | 2001-2500   |
 2745   | 2501-3000   |
 3376   | 3001-3500   |
 4097   | 4001-4500   |
 4914   | 4501-5000   |
 5833   | 5501-6000   |
 6860   | 6501-7000   |
 8001   | 8001-8500   |
 9262   | 9001-9500   |
 10649  | 10001-15000 |
 12168  | 10001-15000 |
 13825  | 10001-15000 |
 15626  | 15001-30000 |
 17577  | 15001-30000 |
 19684  | 15001-30000 |
 21953  | 15001-30000 |
 24390  | 15001-30000 |
 27001  | 15001-30000 |
 29792  | 15001-30000 |
 32769  | 30001-45000 |
 35938  | 30001-45000 |
 39305  | 30001-45000 |
 42876  | 30001-45000 |
 46657  | 45001-60000 |
 50654  | 45001-60000 |
 54873  | 45001-60000 |
 59320  | 45001-60000 |
 64001  | Bottom      |
 68922  | Bottom      |
 74089  | Bottom      |
 79508  | Bottom      |
 85185  | Bottom      |
 91126  | Bottom      |
 97337  | Bottom      |
 103824 | Bottom      |
 110593 | Bottom      |
 117650 | Bottom      |
--------+-------------+
```

#### Possible optimization

If your ranges are always in multiple or 100, you can make a table 100 times smaller, storing only the values ending with `00`, and then join on e.g. `CEIL(rank)+1`.

But then you also need to handle values `1..100` after the join, e.g. `IFNULL(grp, IFF(rank <= 100, rank::varchar, 'Bottom'))`

Comment: I don't think having a lookup table with entry for each possible rank is a good idea, the lookup table should be small having only the ranges (start_rank, end_rank, transaction_group), otherwise reading pages of lookup table during join will overshadow the gain of not computing the group name

Comment: I can guarantee for that order of magnitude, 60000-size table will be WAY faster than what you propose. The problem with your layout is that the join is not an equality join, and these are WAY more expensive. Another thing is that it's trivially possible to reduce it to 600 entries.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply! I'm not an avid user of Stack Overflow, but that indeed helped! Thanks